# Different fields available for different sites when when customising Menu's

Tags: menus, theme-customizer

I have 2x websites, both running identical versions of the same theme, yet when I try to customise the menu's I'm met with different field options.

On Site A I am able to add settings to fields such as **CSS Classes**, **Link Relationship** and **Description**, however on Site B those fields are not available.

Neither site has custom customisation settings, and a brand new install of the theme on a clean DB results in the same settings availability as Site B.

I'm a little stumped by this strange behavior, has anyone experienced this it before?

The images below show the fields available when adding a Custom Link (both via the Custom Link option, and the pseudo Home link under Pages).  I have however confirmed that this behavior persists when adding things like Categories, Tags and Posts to the menu.

[image: Site A]
[image: Site B]

Comment: Care to share the relevant code?

Comment: What code would you like? I have no custom customisation settings, and the only menu location that is registered via **functions.phone** is 'Primary'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is most likely a result of different Screen Options selected between each site.  While on the menu editor, look in the top right corner for the Screen Options pull down.

On that panel, you should have the option to hide or show (via checkbox) details such as the title attribute, link target, CSS classes, etc.

Comment: Thanks for the response, I'll have a look when I get back to the office.  I don't recall ever visiting Appearance -> Menu's though, I prefer to do it all from the Customiser.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, that was indeed correct.  I have no idea when I selected those options for Site A, but guess I must have done so at some point!